# Convert from Object to anything (conditionally)

Tags: java, instanceof, apache-chemistry

I have a method which needs to inspect the value of an Object and determine its datatype and then converts the passed in `value` to the appropriate formatted java datatype. Is there a more elegant way to do this?   switch?  Functional?

I am using Apache Chemistry. The goal is to convert into a type that CMIS will accept. The original code I tried was to use their API to do: PropertyType type = PropertyType.fromValue(value); Originally, I was planning to use this type to determine how to do the conversion. However, the fromValue method is always returning null so I need to get the type from the value itself.

This is what it originally looked like (with Chemistry API):

```
PropertyType type = propertyDefinition.getPropertyType();
if (type.equals(PropertyType.BOOLEAN) {
   return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
```

This only works by getting the type off of the CMIS connection.  I need it to also get the type from a property file so I do not have the API accessible to me, only the value.

```
if (value instanceOf Boolean) {
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
} else if (value instanceof Integer) {
    return Integer.parseInt(value);
} else if (value instanceof Double) {
    return Double.valueOf(value);
} else if (value instanceof DateTime) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = new DateTimeFormatterFactory(format)
        .createDateTimeFormatter();
    return dateFormat.parseDateTime(value).toDate();
} else if (value instanceof String) {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: What is the bigger problem your code code solves that it needs this kind of transformation? Just asking.

Comment: If `value` is a `Boolean`, why on earth are you passing it to `Boolean.parseBoolean()`, which converts a `String` into a `Boolean`?  Likewise for your other types.

Comment: Please show a little more code (what you have doesn't compile at all) and explain what you're trying to really do here.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make any sense.  However you handle the argument, your method returns objects of sufficiently different types that its declared return type can be only `Object`.  In some cases, the apparent intent -- not necessarily achieved -- is to return an object equivalent in type and value to the input object (but having declared type `Object`).  What is the point?

Comment: I assume this function must be declared to return `Object` (otherwise, it would not compile), right? In that case, yeah, there is a "more elegant way":  `return value`

Comment: Please don't try to put code in comments.  If you have more information that enhances/clarifies your question, **edit your question** and add it.

Comment: This appears to be an excerpt of a very peculiar method.  Not only do you have an Object type that can apparently accept a number of arbitrary specific subtypes, it also returns a number of seemingly unrelated types.  I respectfully suggest that this may be a bad design.

Comment: this is a terrible idea.  use overloading instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've properly understood your problem, but I think you've got an object called value, and you want to check what kind of object it is and set the appropriate PropertyType for it. If that's the case, try this:

```
if (value instanceOf Boolean) {
    return PropertyType.BOOLEAN;
} else if (value instanceof Integer) {
    return PropertyType.INTEGER;
} else if (value instanceof Double) {
    return PropertyType.DECIMAL; // well, sort of, maybe.
} else if (value instanceof DateTime) {
    return PropertyType.DATETIME;
} else if (value instanceof String) {
    return PropertyType.STRING;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but that is not what I am looking for.  I am converting FROM a type of a PropertyType.BOOLEAN.

Comment: I was not able to get it to work properly from a properties file, so went back to using the open connection and found this in their documentation:  http://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-read-meta-content.html

Comment: I see. So the variable `value` is obtained from the `Property.getValue()` method and it can be any of a number of types, such as `Integer`, `String` etc. Going back to your original question, you can't have a method that returns different types. You can only return an instance of a type that is the supertype of all the possible return types. But that's already what `value` is: an instance of `Object`. What you want to do is process `value` differently according to what type it is. You can do the type-specific processing for each branch of the `instanceof` test.